# How do I reference a Cell value stored in an excel file on sharepoint in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint

For the purpose of version control for my file, I want to be able to run a script that compares Cell A1 on Sheet VC, to the same cell/sheet of a version stored on Sharepoint when I run my script. Fairly new to using VBA and cant work out how to do it and cant find the answer im looking for on google.

The code I want to use:

```
Public Sub version_control()

Sheets("VC").Calculate

If Sheets("VC").Range("A1").Value <> (this is where I want it to check cell A1 sheet VC on the Sharepoint file)

MsgBox "Please download the latest version from the Sharepoint"

Application.Quit
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guessing, you don't already have the SharePoint file open ... if that's true skip down.

But if it's open you can reference it like any other open workbook ... e.g. both of these should work:

```
debug.Print Workbooks("MySharePointWorkbook.xlsx").Sheets("VC").Range("A1").Value
debug.Print Workbooks.Item(n).Sheets("VC").Range("A1").Value
```

Probably not already open right? Without getting into the weeds of external data links, I would just obtain the full URL of the SharePoint file (open it, `? Activeworkbook.FullName` in the Immediate Window) and store that string in `serverFileName` like this:

```
Public Sub version_control()
    Dim serverFileName As String 'obtain url for sharepoint filename, insert below
    Dim valuesAreDifferent As Boolean 'so we can do housekeeping below
    Dim x As New Excel.Application 'make a new session for the sharepoint version
    Dim w As Workbook 'grab-handle for the sharepoint file
    Sheets("VC").Calculate
    valuesAreDifferent = False 'implicit, being explicit
    serverFileName = "http://whatever-domain.com/MySharepointWorkbook.xlsx"
    x.Visible = False 'so it doesn't flash up when checking
    Set w = x.Workbooks.Open(serverFileName) 'open the sharepoint version
    If Sheets("VC").Range("A1").Value <> w.Sheets("VC").Range("A1").Value Then _
        valuesAreDifferent = True
    'housekeeping in case we don't quit
    w.Close
    x.Quit
    Set w = Nothing
    Set x = Nothing
    If valuesAreDifferent Then
        MsgBox "Please download the latest version from the Sharepoint"
        Application.Quit
    End If
End Sub
```